# A For Loop in Jinja can't be used again or how to move First

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

When reusing the same SQLAlchemy Result to iterate it only works the first time.

See the below how I get all the `qual.workforce` but none of the `displayname`, `busunit` or `certcount's`:

```
    <ul class="empltype">
        {% for qual in allquals %}
<li>{{qual.workforce}}</li>                    
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
   <ul class="names">
        {% for qual in allquals %}
<li>{{qual.displayname}}</li>                 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <ul class="busunit">
        {% for qual in allquals %}
<li>{{qual.busunit}}</li>                    
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <ul class="certcount">
        {% for qual in allquals %}
<li>{{qual.certcount}}</li>                    
        {% endfor %}
```

I would like to MoveFirst before the 3 loops for displaynames, busunit and certcount so they all work.

I don't want have 4 copies of the same variable (allquals1,2,3) even though I know that will work. I'm guessing the `jinja` render engine only iterates through objects once, is there a way to tell it to iterate over the same result set each time its used in a loop?

[image]

Comment: I guess this is expected behavior. `allqual` is probably an iterator. Once you iterated over the elemets of an iterator, it is done and you cannot reiterate.

Comment: Agreed, it's been iterated. Thing is DB drivers 30yrs ago provided MoveFirst, my Google Fu is failing to find it for SqlAlchemy

Comment: So what about turning the sqlalchemy iterator into a list and work with that ?

Comment: @smido, I'm a newbie to all these technologies, any chance you could show me how or a link? Is that working with the ResultProxy? thanks

Comment: To clarify, "MoveFirst" I'm looking for a way in the engine. I can do it using allquals1,2,3. I wonder if I can just declare them in the jinja

Comment: In the code where you prepare your allquals variable for template context, you would just do `list(allquals)`. Maybe you can share the code that prepares the template context if you need more help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it happens just because the result is a generator, and it's values can be accessed only once. you have to do `allquals = list(query_result)` to iterate multiple times over it